# Subtract values from same column based on dates and keep using the result if it is negative

Tags: sql, sql-server

| DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-04-12 | 2178 |
| 2019-05-31 | 2178 |
| 2020-06-30 | 15244,5 |
| 2021-09-20 | 16498,34 |
| 2022-02-02 | -16367,4 |

I have this table in SQL.

What I need to do is to subtract the positive values from the negative values until the result is positive starting from the first date. For example, 2178 - 16367,4 = -14.189,4‬. This last number I need to subtract it again from 2178. So the new result is -12.011,4‬. As the result is still negative, I will subtract 15244,5 -12.011,4‬. The result for evident reasons is going to be positive so I have to keep this positive result as the new VALUE for the date 2020-06-30. So my desired new table would be:

| DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06-30 | 3233,1 |
| 2021-09-20 | 16498,34 |

Any idea how to do this in SQL?

Comment: And I can't follow your logic... maybe add a table showing the working.

Comment: i think this would be better solved in a loop and a programming language or stored procedure

Comment: I need the answer on SQL. The logic of the problem is not complex, what is complex is to program it.

Comment: We don't seem to be able to understand how you choose which rows to add or subtract. Can you show how you decide that?

Comment: You didn't provide a description of the process.  How do you determine you should start with 2178 - 16367,4?  There also seems to be some confusion regarding the definition of some terms:  subtract, positive, and negative.

Comment: What is the real question?  Some people work better with real-world reasons to use computers to do things.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Is this a case where a customer has racked up a tab based on unpaid purchases on specific dates, then the negative numbers indicate payments?  So you're looking for the remaining balance on old debts in order of date?

Comment: I suppose closing this is approprate.  It is a clear XY problem.  https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it!

```
DROP TABLE YourTable

CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
    Date DATE,
    Value DECIMAL(10, 2)
)
GO

INSERT INTO YourTable
VALUES
('2019-04-12', '2178'),
('2019-05-31', '2178'),
('2020-06-30', '15244.5'),
('2021-09-20', '16498.34'),
('2022-02-02', '-16367.4')

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD RowNumber INT NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CalculatedValue DECIMAL(10, 2) NULL
GO

UPDATE A
SET A.RowNumber = A.Ranks
FROM
(
    SELECT RowNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE ASC) AS Ranks
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Value > 0
) A

UPDATE YourTable
SET CalculatedValue =
(
    SELECT SUM(Value)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Value < 0
) + Value
WHERE RowNumber = 1

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @iMax INT =
(
    SELECT MAX(RowNumber)
    FROM YourTable
)

WHILE @i <= @iMax
BEGIN
    UPDATE A
    SET A.CalculatedValue = B.CalculatedValue + A.Value
    FROM YourTable A
    JOIN YourTable B ON
        A.RowNumber = @i
        AND B.RowNumber = @i - 1
SET @i = @i + 1
END

UPDATE YourTable
SET CalculatedValue = Value
WHERE RowNumber > 
(
    SELECT MIN(RowNumber)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CalculatedValue > 0
)

SELECT Date, CalculatedValue AS 'Value'
FROM YourTable
WHERE CalculatedValue >= 0
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

OK.  Spitballing here based on an assumed requirement

> A customer has racked up a tab based on unpaid purchases on specific dates, then the negative numbers indicate payments.  If payments are applied to debts in date order, what is the remaining balance from each date?

```
create table t (
  dt date,
  val decimal(8,3)
)

insert t
values 
  ({d '2019-04-12'}, 2178)
, ({d '2019-05-31'}, 2178)
, ({d '2020-06-30'}, 15244.5)
, ({d '2021-09-20'}, 16498.34)
, ({d '2022-02-02'}, -16367.4)

;
with a as (
  select dt
  , val
  , SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY case when val < 0 then 1 else 2 end, dt ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as oldbal
  from t
),
b as (
  select dt
  , val + case when oldbal < 0 then oldbal else 0 end as RemainingBalance
  from a
)
select dt as 'DATE'
, RemainingBalance as 'VALUE'
from b
where RemainingBalance > 0
order by dt
;

--  Correct values for comparison
select cast([DATE] as date) as 'DATE'
, VALUE
from (
  values 
    ({d '2020-06-30'}, 3233.1)
  , ({d '2021-09-20'}, 16498.34)
) q ([DATE], [VALUE])
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4de0258c6e670d6d4d7e8b4f717eb82a

Comment: That seems to give `19731.440` as the second value?

Comment: You are correct.  It was the end of the day.  Apparently, I didn't complete all my testing.  Thinking I'm on the right path, I'll try to complete/correct this today.

Comment: Since the question is closed, I can't correct the answer.  I guess my wrong answer goes down in history for all humanity to mock.  nice.

Comment: You can still edit your answer can't you? I can lol

Comment: Well, nothing happened when I hit save.  It appears to be there now.  Maybe you could because you have more points?

Comment: Pretty sure you can edit your own answers anytime.